# C++ How to use relative error with `cout`?

Tags: c++, printing, floating-point, double, cout

While preparing for my first ever coding interview I found a question where I was requested to print a double number with an absolute or relative error of `10^(-6)`.

How can I do something like that with `cout`?

```
double test_var; // Holding Some value which changes according to my program.
cout << test_var << endl;
```

Plus, In the expected output I saw numbers like `1000.00` how can I print those `.00` too?

Comment: how does relative/absolute error of 10^(-6) make sense for a `bool` ? The question is not quite clear, though when you are talking about floating point numbers you are maybe looking for `std::setprecision`

Comment: can you add some examples with values and expected output?

Comment: regarding the examples this is the only one they provided.

Comment: it is still confusing because now it is an `int` but question is tagged with `floating-point`. Do you want output `1000.00` for `int test_var = 1000;` ? Or is the question about printing floating-point values?

Comment: It's my first question, again sorry it's double I don't know what happened to me today :)

Comment: who is "they" ? If thats the only code they provided you, then you should protest, because `test_var` is not initialzed, no messing around with `std::cout` can fix that

Comment: test_var has changing value in my program that's why I left it empty. refer to my problem as general how to print double with relative error of 10^(-6)?

Comment: why dont you write `double test_var = 100.0;` instead of explaining how the code you posted is different from the actual code ;) Please read about [mcve]

Comment: I don't know what's the value inside test_var it's changing according to input. Again refer to my sentence above consider it as general problem How to print double with relative error of 10^(-6)? @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: you are probably looking for `std::setprecision`, but (again) I am not sure what you are actually asking for, an example with input and desired output would clarify that

Comment: “Print a double number with an absolute or relative error of 10^(-6)” does not make sense. If we want to print a number, we print it. We do not just add error to it to prin it. Perhaps the question author meant to print with at least six digits after the decimal point and correct rounding (so the absolute error is less than 10^-6) or with six or seven significant digits (intending to ensure the relative error is less than 10^-6). So the question is actually about how to use formatting options in C++. If so, they have posed the question poorly…

Comment: … Consider that printing with six digits after the decimal point, correctly rounded, is sufficient to ensure absolute error at most 10^-6 (at most ½ of that if round-to-nearest is used), but it is not always necessary. For example, if the number is 3, then printing “3” with no digits after the decimal place prints it with zero error, so six digits after the decimal point are not necessary. So asking how to print a number with absolute error at most 10^-6 fails to ask how to use the formatting options to produce six digits after the decimal point.

Comment: … I also suspect (based on little direct evidence, but I have seen enough to know this is a possibility) that asking about limiting the relative error to 10^-6 was intended to solicit formatting with six significant digits, but actually seven may be needed. E.g., consider 100,001.4. If it is formatted to six significant digits, the result is 100,001, but the relative error in that is .4/100,001.4, which is about 4•10^-6.

Comment: @Sholy "absolute or relative error of 10^(-6)." --> Which one do you want?  Answers so far only show _absolute_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have used [std::setprecision](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
  double f =3.14159;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n'; //prints 3.1416
  std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << f << '\n'; //prints 3.14159
  std::cout << std::fixed;   //Modifies the default formatting for floating-point input/output.  
  std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n'; //prints 3.1416
  std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << f << '\n'; //prints 3.141590000   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so i think its complicated with those set or fixes

there is a simple way to acheive your goal

```
printf("%.6lf",test_var);
```

so `%.6lf` means to keep 6 demicals of the varible